# Python3 - Using the bsdiff module

Tags: python3

How do I use the `bsdiff` module with Python? While I can use shell scripts I would prefer to have a cross-platform solution.

I have downloaded bsdiff4-1.1.4 and attempt to run setup.py as follows:

Files list:

```
bsdiff4  build  CHANGELOG.txt  do.sh  examples  Makefile  README.rst  setup.py
```

I run:

```
python3 setup.py build
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:     'entry_points'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'bsdiff4.core' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g     -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security     -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c bsdiff4/core.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/bsdiff4/core.o
bsdiff4/core.c:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install python3-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```